# Replying to a User's wall message using Facebook C# SDK

Tags: facebook, c#-4.0, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

Is there a way to reply to the user's wall comments using the Facebook C# SDK?  I'm using following code for wall posting:

```
var fb = new FacebookClient(facebookOAuthResult.AccessToken);
dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();
parameters.message = "test";
dynamic postresult = fb.Post("me/feed", parameters);
```

Comment: Can there be a way to Post like  fb.Post("me/feed/message_id") .. this message_id is the wall's Original Post ID..??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I'm understanding this question correctly.  I'm assuming this is the use case:

1. User posts a status update(the ID of this post is "12345")
2. User's friend writes a comment for that status update
3. User writes on a comment on the status update made in Step.1

```cs
try  
{  
    String statusUpdateID = "12345";  
    fb.Post(String.Format("/{0}/comments", statusUpdateID), parameters);  
}  
catch (FacebookOAuthException e)  
{  
    //this exception is thrown if your comment fails to post  
}
```

That should do it!  Of course, make sure that statusUpdateID is set to the actual ID of the message you want to comment on.

Also, you do NOT need to store the return value of 'fb.Post(),' it is the ID of the comment you just made.

Answer (score 0):

To comment on a post, HTTP POST to `{POSTID}\Comments` with `message` as a post parameter

See http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/ for more information on the `comments` connection and how to *create* a comment.

```
Create

You can write to the POST_ID/comments connection to post a comment to the post by issuing an HTTP POST request with the publish_stream permission and following parameters.

Parameter    Description     Type    Required
message Comment text    string   yes

If the write is successful, you get the following return.

Name     Description     Type
id   The new comment ID string
```